# I am am connected to my wireless router at home but it won’t give me an Internet connection

Tags: linux, internet, wireless-router, linux-mint, networkmanager

I have a Thinkpad running Linux Mint 17 and my connection is on `wlan0` which is the Intel Wi-Fi interface.

Several days ago I was connected to the Wi-Fi router at home and everything worked like a charm. Then I closed my Thinkpad and it was sent to hibernate mode. Later at the University I was also able to connect to their WPA2-Enterprise (radius-managed) Wi-Fi.

Back at home, I wake up my laptop, fired up the Wi-Fi connection, got an IP address, but then nothing works. I have no Internet connectivity:

All ping requests to public IPs and Domain Servers timed out. The Wi-Fi router was also not reachable via ping (which may be an security feature).

Here are some things I have done so far.

- Reconnected serveral times to the router
- Deleted the credentials of the networkmanager and entered it again
- Restarted the networkmanager using sudo service network-manager restart
- Installed wicd and disabled networkmanager at boot by renaming it's startup files
- Inspected rfkill to see, if there is something blocking the wireless interface
- Booted a linux live CD to see, if theres any issue to the configuration files
- Set DNS and gateway manually (using 8.8.8.8 and the routers local IP)
- Booting my windows partition and connecting to the wifi router give me internet access as usual.

Comment: Did you try unplugging your router and modem, waiting 30 seconds, and plugging it back in? Could be a simple fix if that's all there is.  If this doesn't fix it then can you tell me if your computer sees the router? To do this simply enter the router's IP address into your browser.

Comment: I restarted the router several times. My computer does not see the router. It is not reachable via browser nor ping request. But it obtains a valid IP address via DHCP from the router. My phone, which is working, uses the same IP range.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like Linux Mint drivers for WLAN is causing the issue, please connect to Internet through LAN and try the following commands on terminal:

sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer

sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi

sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

Please try this and check the status